# Connect two local linux computers via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to know how to connect two linux computers (Ubuntu and OpenSuse) via SSH. When I try to run this command on Suse:

```
ssh 192.168.1.37
```

I get error:

> ssh : connect to host 192.168.1.37 port 22 : connection refused.

When I try to connect from Ubuntu PC with the same command and Suse's IP, I get "connection timeout" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Install SSH server in the machine you want to connect, by issuing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y
```

After that, you can connect to that machine by executing the following command:

```
ssh user@ip_address
```

where `user` is the name of the user in that machine you want to connect to with which you want to be authenticated, and `ip_address` is the IP address of that same machine.

Comment: Is sudo needed?, why?

Comment: Not necessary. Updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When logging in, try to specify the user you want as well, so that the command looks something like this

`ssh example@192.168.1.37`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command by specifying the username followed by `@` and the IP address (i.e. the hostname).

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1
```

Here, `user` is the username of the user in the machine you want to connect to, followed by the IP address of the host, which in this case is `192.168.1.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this if its default user

```
ssh root@192.168.1.16

ssh root@device_ip_address
```

root is the default user for dietpi